# Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126

Tags: python, tensorflow, cudnn

```
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126
Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!
```

I keep getting this error when I try to use TensorFlow with GPU, I've installed CUDA, cuDNN, and all the drivers multiple times according to the instructions. But nothing seems to work.
If I use notebook then TensorFlow uses the CPU, with VS code notebook extension i can use the gpu but it stops the session at 1st epoch, when I tried to run it as a normal python file. the above error occurred.

Complete terminal output:

```
Found 14630 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes.
Found 1500 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes.
2021-11-08 11:03:58.000354: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-11-08 11:03:58.603592: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2775 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1        
Epoch 1/10
2021-11-08 11:04:07.306011: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8300
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126
Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!
E:\MyWorkSpace\animal_detect>
```

The code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
from tensorflow.keras import layers 
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,rotation_range = 40, width_shift_range = 0.2, height_shift_range = 0.2, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
train_set = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df,x_col='loc',y_col='label',batch_size=20,target_size=(224,224))
test_set = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(test_df,x_col='loc',y_col='label',batch_size=20,target_size=(224,224))
base_model = VGG16(input_shape = (224, 224, 3),
include_top = False,
weights = 'imagenet')
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(base_model.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['acc'])
vgghist = model.fit(train_set, validation_data = test_set, steps_per_epoch = 100, epochs = 10)
```

the same code has been used for Jupyter-notebook, VS code notebook extension and as a normal python file

Device specifications:

processor: Intel i5
gpu: Nvidia Geforce 1050ti

Cuda version: 11.5
cuDNN version: 8.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66355477/681865

Comment: @talonmies already tried, not working for me

Answer (score 37):

For those still having this issue, please make sure you also have completed [this step](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows):

[image]

Download, unzip and add `zlibwapi.dll` to your system path. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I did ignore this installation guide（That's my fault）. I have compiled tf2.7 for cuda11.5 and cudnn8.3 vary far days ago but cannot use cudnn8.3 until added zlibwapi.dll to system path.  Although zlibwapi. dll does not affect the use of cudnn8.2, it does affect the correct operation of  cudnn8.3.

Comment: I think this is the most correct solution, since it is included in the official cuDNN installation guide. Also, there is no need to downgrade the cuDNN version.

Comment: Wow. There were so many gotchas in getting CuDNN accepted when installing dlib.  And after I managed to get it installed, this zlib thing was a final gotcha preventing my python script from getting cuDNN.  Thank you.

Comment: link is expired

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Link mentioned in the answer works but the link to ZLIB DLL is expired. http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/zlib123dllx64.zip

Comment: @ShirishBajpai Aw man. You are right. They didn't maintain their api docs up to date :facepalm:

Comment: CUDA 11.8 and CUDNN 8.9 here. I installed zlib, added the zlibwapi.dll into the relevant folder. I still get a similar error,  difference being there is no error code.  Could not locate cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll. Please make sure it is in your library path! I also already made sure cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll is already in the bin folder in the CUDA folder

Comment: DO NOT download zip files from random websites. I don't know why nvidia  is hiding it that good but here's an official answer with matching downlods: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/could-not-load-library-cudnn-cnn-infer64-8-dll-error-code-193/218437/16

Answer (score 17):

The same "errors" as me. Even though I have re-compiled the tensorflow-gpu 2.6.0 with "Cuda version: 11.5 cuDNN version: 8.3".
The "errors" disappeared when I changed cudnn version to 8.2 but kept cuda version as 11.5. (Re-compiled is als needed)
So I think this error must on "cuDNN".

Please See androidu's answer. It worked perfectly.

Comment: that fixed it for me, thx! i went for `Download cuDNN v8.2.2 (July 6th, 2021), for CUDA 11.4`

Comment: it also worked for me: downloaded and installed **CUDA Toolkit 11.5**, then Download the incompatible cuDNN v8.2.4 (September 2nd, 2021), for **CUDA 11.4**, placed the files in correct folders as in https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html, and voily, THE PAIN IS GONE! THX @Little Train

Comment: Thanks! This helped me too. I have CUDA Toolkit 11.5 and had cuDNN v8.3.0.

Comment: @jib-fashr Works for me. Thank you!

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved in an unbelievable way.

Comment: For 10.1 CUDA Tensorflow complained about CUDArt 11 so I downloaded 11.2 CUDA then matching cuDNN 8.3 but it didn't work, until I tried this solution and got cuDNN 8.2

Comment: Just try adding `zlibwapi.dll` to your system path, there is no need to downgrade. See my answer below. Good luck.