# I am getting the same error "Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126" after trying different versions of Cuda and Cudnn

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter to build a deep learning image processing model. Here is my model architecture

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=15,
rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.1,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
width_shift_range=0.1,
height_shift_range=0.1)

train_datagenerator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_data,
                                                     x_col="image_path",
                                                     y_col="labels",
                                                     target_size=(150, 150),
                                                     class_mode="binary",
                                                     batch_size=64)
```

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagenerator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_data,
                                                   x_col="image_path",
                                                   y_col="labels",
                                                   target_size=(150, 150),
                                                   class_mode="binary",
                                                   batch_size=64)
```

**and I have been facing a huge problem for couple days now which is the kernel is dying everytime I reach the training code line**

```
history = model.fit(train_datagenerator, epochs=20)
```

and I am getting this error code on the cmd window of jupyter (Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126)
keep in mind that I have added Cudnn to my enviroment path, and for the last couple days I have tried differen versions of cuda, CUDnn, and tensorflow but they are all giving me the same error.

and atm I am using python 3.9, Cudnn for 11.5 cuda 8.3.1 , tensorflow 3.7 , cuda 11.5.

please Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879188/could-not-load-library-cudnn-cnn-infer64-8-dll-error-code-126

Comment: Yes. the Second solution worked for me. Thank you very much.